# Why did the Fed increase the fixed rate of I-bond to 1.3% from 0.4% for the US?

Tags: united-states, federal-reserve

What could be the cause of this increase? Would the trend continue? Why or why not?

Comment: They didn't.  The federal reserve doesn't make that decision, the Treasury does.

Comment: @jjanes I'm confused about the responsibilities between Fed and the Treasury. Could you please briefly describe who does what? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/articles/economics/08/treasury-fed-reserve.asp

Comment: @DStanley According to the article, the Fed "adjusts the interest rates paid for U.S. Treasuries, bonds, and other debt issued by the Treasury. ", so the Fed is the one who raises the fixed rate of I bonds?

Comment: (@DStanley) _many_ claims in that article are wrong. The Fed does not directly set rates for any Treasury security. It does effectively set the interbank funding rate, which drives short-term market rates for _all_ issuers because they compete with bank loans for investors. The short-term market rate _and_ the Fed's QE/QT both _influence_ but do not set long-term market rates, where Treasuries also compete. So Fed policy has some indirect effect on Treasury rates, but only along with all rates for all (new or tradable) products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not seen any specific rationale for the setting of the fixed rate, but my assumption would be that it's based on treasury rates to be competitive with treasury bonds (why would you buy a bond at a lower floating rate when you could get a higher fixed rate?)
In short, the Treasury sets the fixed rate to be just high enough to be attractive to investors while minimizing the amount of interest they pay.

> Would the trend continue? Why or why not?

No one knows - you could look at the Treasury yield curve and see if the *market* thinks that interest rates in general will go up or down, but even that is a guess, and does not *directly* affect the fixed rate for I-bonds.